# How to change div position

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lFSN.jpg)

How to put ,,Kontakty" in brown place ? How to center Strona Główna/Projekty/O mnie in blue/orange/green/brown? I'm newbie and it's probably easy af --randomtextwhichallowmepublicthis-----randomtextwhichallowmepublicthis-----randomtextwhichallowmepublicthis-----randomtextwhichallowmepublicthis---

```css
 
 
 
body
{
    background: url(bg.jpg);
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
 
div.container
{
    width:1140px;
}
 
div.nav
{
    position:absolute;
 
    width:100%;
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive ;
    color: rgb(161, 240, 161);
    font-size:60px;
     /*
        padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
        top padding is 25px
        right padding is 50px
        bottom padding is 75px
        left padding is 100px
    */
 
}
 
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
 
li.top
{
    width:540px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="container">
            <div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="top">Strona główna</li>
        <li class="top">Projekty</li>
        <li class="top">O mnie</li>
        <li class="top"> Kontakt</li>
    </ul>
            </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to let others do your job. So please consider reducing your question to an abstract problem, that can be understood and answered by others. Maybe read this here before starting to question anything: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Later keep in mind the following points:
1. Update your code snippet to a running code that fits your problem case.
2. Add more value to your question by beeing more accurate and explicit.
3. Add some side information like, is your side responsive etc.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body
{
    background: url(bg.jpg);
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
 
div.container
{
    width:1140px;
}
 
div.nav
{
    position:absolute;
 
    width:100%;
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive ;
    color: rgb(161, 240, 161);
    font-size:60px;
     /*
        padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
        top padding is 25px
        right padding is 50px
        bottom padding is 75px
        left padding is 100px
    */
 
}
 
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display:inline;
  font-size:22px !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="container">
            <div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="top">Strona główna</li>
        <li class="top">Projekty</li>
        <li class="top">O mnie</li>
        <li class="top"> Kontakt</li>
    </ul>
            </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when u want to align content in 'li' in single line you have to use css "display:inline" or "display:inline-block;" for li................You can observe that in my code